# Hiding a Bar button item in the view

Tags: iphone

How can you able to hide the (done) bar button item in a view? 
Basically, I have a view controller added with navigation bar (in IB) then, I also added a bar button item into the nav bar.
I just want initially the (done) bar button item is hidden.. when input is in the text view the (done) button is already visible.

Any idea on this implementation on a view controller?

Here's my sample code:

```
@interface MyTextViewViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> 
{
 UITextView *m_textView;
 UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButtonItem;   
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *m_textView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButtonItem;

- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender;
```

.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    doneBarButtonItem.hidden = YES;   --> compile error!!!
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{ 
    doneBarButtonItem.hidden = NO;   --> compile error!!!
}

- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender
{
    doneBarButtonItem.hidden = YES;   --> compile error!!!
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following technique :

1. Remove the image : self.barButtonItem.image = nil;
2. Reset width of Button : self.barButtonItem.width = 0.0f;

This worked for me.

Comment: with this approach the button may seem to disappear but it is really there. If you tap on it, it has the flow effect and action working, which you don't want. This is a buggy approach.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work perfectly and has the same user effects

```
doneBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

The other solution is add it only when user already enters something and remove it when there is nothing

Comment: With this approach the button still shows but it is disabled. This doesn't work for when you need the button to be completely removed, such as for advanced features only enabled for certain users.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjustment the background position to accomplish this:

```
[doneBarButtonItem setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:1000000 forBarMetrics:1000000];
```

Set the offset of the background position to a very large value to hide it.

```
[doneBarButtonItem setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.0000000000001 forBarMetrics:0.0000000000000001];
```

Then switch it back like this.

Note: You must set both offsets to a value greater than 0 to get back the button, otherwise it won't show up.

Comment: Doesn't work? It works for me on iOS SDK 6.1. Which version of iOS SDK you are using?

Answer (score 0):

None of the options above worked for me. The clean approach is to have an IBOutlet to the toolbar and use the setItems method to add/remove the button from from it.
While the button is hidden, I maintain a strong reference to it, so I can show it again later.
This code assumes you set up the xib for this RootViewController with the toolbar and bar button that you wish to hide/show later.

```
 @interface RootViewController()

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem * barButtonItem;

    @end


    - (void) showSettingsBarButtonItem{

        NSMutableArray * toolbarButtonItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
                                                 [self.toolbar items]];

        bool found = NO;

        for(UIBarButtonItem * tmpButton in toolbarButtonItems){

            if([tmpButton tag] == 500){ //settings button.

                //keep it
                found = YES;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found == NO){

            [toolbarButtonItems insertObject:self.barButtonItem atIndex:1]; //insert item at index you like.

            [self.toolbar setItems:toolbarButtonItems];
        }
    }

    - (void) hideSettingsBarButtonItem{


        NSMutableArray * toolbarButtonItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
                                               [self.toolbar items]];

        bool found = NO;

        for(UIBarButtonItem * tmpButton in toolbarButtonItems){

            if([tmpButton tag] == 500){ //settings button tag. set in IB.

                found = YES;
                self.barButtonItem = tmpButton; //save it for later.
                                                //should keep a reference to your VC.

                [toolbarButtonItems removeObject:tmpButton];

                break;
            }
        }

        if(found == YES){

            [self.toolbar setItems:toolbarButtonItems];
        }
    }
```